# Twilio Video Freezing during query loading

Tags: html5-video, twilio

We have a UI running web queries to update dynamic content that is paired with a twilio video integration. The twilio video (though not sound) seems to freeze (sometimes temporarily, and sometimes permanently) while users are interacting with the screen content and kicking off the web queries.

Can any one help with a method to keep the video feed from freezing regardless of what is happening on the input side?

This is fairly consistent no matter if we are using a touchscreen or a mouse. We are using Chrome as our browser of choice for our kiosk application.

Any help or requests for clarifying information are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like whatever other JavaScript you are running is doing work on the main thread and causing the video to slow down. What does the code that runs the web queries and updates look like?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find a functional solution by pulling the twilio video into it's own Iframe so that the main page and the video were being handled in separate processes. It was probably not the most elegant solution but it is currently functioning without any degraded functionality caused by the javascript processes of the main page.